# Why are you censoring common words from question titles?

Tags: discussion, support

Just a few minutes ago, I began to write a question on StackOverflow when the following message popped up: "These words are not allowed in titles: problem"

What is going on here?

Comment: Voting down?  Please comment and explain why.  I'm frustrated by this new policy, but if it serves a good purpose, please explain.

Comment: It's not a particularly new thing and it's aimed at people who write "help plz with my problem" as titles. See for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115492/block-but-automatically-flag-problem-attempts-in-the-title-as-low-quality

Comment: It's a very old policy. Hold on, looking up the Meta post...

Comment: For what it's worth, my proposed question title is `Strange problem importing my Oracle view into an Entity Data Model`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161398/houston-we-have-a-porblem - incidentally, it's the Meta post with the funniest title ever

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: "Strange problem" - can you pick a more descriptive phrase for that part? Or just drop it entirely.

Comment: The post referenced by Pekka is about people permuting the letters in words to avoid the filter.  It says nothing about *why* words are filtered.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to condense an unexpected error message into a question title.

Comment: The "problem" filter has always been extremely unpopular among the communty. I can't find the original post from Jeff right now, but essentially they found that  use of the word "problem" correlates with bad question titles, and bad questions in general. So much so that they decided to block it, for better or for worse. (Edit: here are some numbers that Kevin Montrose extracted from the question base: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter?lq=1)

Comment: Note too that the word "problem" is always redundant in question titles.  After all, if you _didn't_ have a problem, you wouldn't be posting a question on SO in the first place.  Open-ended debating and playful questions are off-topic, so all you can ask about is problems.

Comment: I wouldn't take it to heart that much, this kind of policies aren't meant to wind up people, but to avoid a very generic pattern of titles as they are later much harder to find (both in the SO search bar and other search engines). For example, under the `android` tag you see dozens of questions with "Unfortunately, <appname> has stopped" as title per day, which is the default error that appears when an unhandled Exception happens. No descriptive at all. I know it's not your case, but if that prevents general titles, I support it.

Comment: Try "Unable to import...". More descriptive, and you can elaborate on your surprise and confusion in the post itself. Also, I completely empathize with Oracle problems, and I bet that at the moment, you're more frustrated with your database than with StackOverflow. StackOverflow is just adding a piece of hay on top of a mountain.

Comment: "Unable to" is hardly more descriptive than "problem", but yes, I am very frustrated and the last thing I wanted was to be told that my question title is unacceptable.  It seems like an arbitrary rule to me; I'm surprised I haven't run into it before.

Comment: I support the policy of basic title filtering (even if it is frustrating to those of us who edit questions that seem to have escaped the filter in the first place!). My pet hate is people who add "Please help" (or worse yet, "Plz hlp") to titles or subject bodies. It is noise, and I remove it. Anyway... if you rephrase your title as a question (which is the recommended style anyway, I think) then the "problem" goes away: _How to import an Oracle view into an Entity Data Model?_

Comment: It's improving your chances of your question actually being seen and understood, instead of being lost among the millions of questions that would be phrased as "Problem with my code" or "Problem with my app" or "Problem with something" by making you be more descriptive with the issue you're facing. Clearly you have a "problem", or you wouldn't be asking for help here to find a solution. :-)

Comment: It's not so important, but as per my suggested title, I'd recommend changing "my" into a/an as well. If a question is only about _your_ Oracle views, it is too localised and thus can be voted to be placed on hold. But if it applies to all Oracle views in the situation you describe, then it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 9):

**Do not depend on a free Internet resource for time-critical work.**  If your work is that critical, hire a consultant or get a support contract from a suitable company. (in other news, it's nice to know that some folks actually finds Stack Overflow to be a valuable resource, predictions of its impending doom to the contrary).

That said, I've never quite understood the rationale for this particular "feature."  "Problem" is an actual word used in some programming terms, so it's not like it's entirely useless.  My understanding is that these stop words are chosen because they strongly correlate with low-quality questions, so the choice of words is not going to make any sense logically (it being a statistical calculation, not a rational one).  It would be one thing if moderators could override this, but we can't, for a number of technical reasons (someone editing the post would just break it again).

I personally think a better approach would be to simply work the stop words into the question quality heuristic with a weighting, like everything else that is used to identify low-quality questions (it would make legitimate uses of the word pass muster), but hey, what do I know?

Comment: Witness the difficulties with the ["halting problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192515/how-to-ask-about-the-halting-problem-on-stackoverflow-regarding-the-title-fil). Kevin does [make an argument in support of this with some data](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter), but I agree that it's a bit of a blunt instrument.

Comment: See also this gem, which is what happens when people work around the filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296272/proble-with-java-platform-collision

Comment: Your example illustrates that the filter doesn't catch everything.

Answer (score 4):

> Do you really believe that you're fulfilling your vision of making the internet a better place to get expert answers to questions by censoring the word "problem" from my question?

Yes. It improves titles. "Problem with X" is bad. "X" is good. Saying that you have a problem doesn't help anybody, we all have problems, that's what questions are. When I see "Strange problem importing my Oracle view into an Entity Data Model"… what is the question about? I have no idea. You could make the title an error message, "How to … ?". But not "problem" - That's a useless word.

Comment: "Strange error" could be hugely improved by stating the error itself, and removing the word "strange". After all, the error is evidently thought to be strange - if it were expected then the OP wouldn't be posting about it `;)`.

Comment: @halfer Yeah, that's a weak title, edited.

Comment: `Strange importing my Oracle view into an Entity Data Model` makes it sound like your girlfriend is doing your job for you...  Hardly easier to understand it that way.  Why don't we do away with "strange" and "error" as well?  I mean... the gamification was fun for a while but I think I'm about done with Stack Overflow after seeing this kind of thing.